# DataGridView is editable but does not send changes back to database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I've bound my `DataGridView` to my `ComboBox` so that whatever value is selected in the `ComboBox`, the corresponding valued for SID and Mark will appear in the `DataGridView`. The `DataGridView` is editable when I do this but the data is not saved in the database when it is input. Is there a way to update it? If there's another method, I have to first warn that I only need SID and Mark in the `DataGridView`, if I try to bind the whole "Student_Course" table to the `DataGridView` I get other columns I don't need.

```
private void cboeCID_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var CID = Convert.ToInt32(cboeCID.Text);
    using (var db = new Entities2())
    {
        var course = from c in db.Student_Course
                     where c.CID == CID
                     select new Class1
                     {
                         SID = c.SID,
                         Mark = c.Mark
                     };
        editDataGridView.DataSource = course.ToList();
        Validate();
        editDataGridView.EndEdit();
        editDataGridView.Update();
    }
}

class Class1
{
    public int SID { get; set; }
    public int Mark { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I originally answered the 1st question because I didn't know you wanted to save back to the DB. Note that after copying the data into the List that makes up the DataSource, there is no more connection to the DB. You can either create a new connection maybe with a DataAdapter, DataTable etc.. or simply bind to the full table after all. There is no problem __hiding__ any __unwanted columns__ from a DataGridView.

Comment: Something like what I edited? Its on the bottom

Comment: Well, that does hide some columns. As I don't use EF I can't comment if anything is missing wrt writing back to the DB, though.

Comment: @Anon Since your new question is more about hiding columns, I posted a complete example for your new question. Also reverted this question to previous version, because the edit which you made may confuse future readers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some important issues in above code:

1. You shaped the result of query to a custom `Class1` which is not your entity type.
2. You used a [`DbContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=entity-framework-6.2.0) in `using` statement which means `db` is disposed after the using statement and will not track changes.
3. You called `SaveChanges` on another instance of your `DbContext` which is not aware of changes, so nothing happens.

To solve above issues consider these tips:

1. Create `db` as a field of `Form` and instantiate it in `Load` event of `Form` and use it for both loading and saving data.
2. You can load data entity this way:

   ```
   db = new Entities2();
   db.Student_Course.Where(x => c.CID== CID).ToList();
   editDataGridView.DataSource = db.Student_Course.Local;
   ```
3. You can save data this way:

   ```
   editDataGridView.EndEdit();
   db.SaveChanges();
   ```
4. If you need to use a view model different than your entity for edit, when saving changes you should first load original entities from database using another instance of your context, then for each entity set the value of changed field and then call `SaveChanges` method.

For more information take a look at these resources:

- [Entity Framework Databinding with WinForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/databinding/winforms?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [Entity Framework Add/Attach Entity States](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: Is something like what I added to the question preferable to what I did previously? Or is that basically the same thing?

Comment: It's completely better, but save changes should be called in another method.

Comment: Yup. I just put the save changes into a button. Now it works :) Thanks so much!!