# Prevent a data grid from loading Entity Framework navigation properties in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a database (Firebird to be specific, but I believe the issue is something to do with EF). I have generated the code files using Code First from Database. The code generated for example for a Driver is:

```
[Table("Firebird.DRIVER")]
public partial class DRIVER
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public DRIVER()
    {
        FAREs = new HashSet<FARE>();
    //..... and other code generated for the other collections
    }


    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int DRIVERID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string FULLNAME { get; set; }
    //... and other properties


    public int? EQUIPMENTID { get; set; }

    public virtual EQUIPMENT EQUIPMENT { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<FARE> FAREs { get; set; }
    //.... and other code generated for the other collections

 }
```

I have a basic form with a DataGridView. The purpose of the DataGridView is to edit, add or delete new entities (Drivers). I bind it this way

```
    private async Task BindGrid()
    {
        var DBContext = AppVariables.CreateContext();
        await Task.Run(() => DBContext.DRIVERs.Load());
        var bindingSource = DBContext.DRIVERs.Local.ToBindingList();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
    }
```

However, I get in my grid the navigation properties (for example EQUIPMENT). What can I do to remove the navigation properties from loading in the grid. Should I delete the navigation property from code first? Or is there another way to load the data into the grid without loading the navigation properties?

I have tried to create objects using only the properties and avoiding the navigation one but the grid wouldn't be editable

```
    private async Task BindGrid()
    {
        var list = from driver in DBContext.DRIVERs
                   select new
                   {
                       DRIVERID = destination.DRIVERID
                       //...
                   };
        await list.LoadAsync();
        var bindingSource = list.ToBindingList();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
    }
```

Comment: Prevent loading is different from prevent showing. If it's about visibility of the column, you can set the `Visible` property of the column to false or remove it at all. You also can set `Browsable(false)` for the property in your class. If it's about loading, first of all, disable lazy loading, then make sure you are not including the column in the query.

Comment: A side note about the first `BindGrid` method which you shared: To be able to save changes, you need to use the same instance of dbcontext which you used for load. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38930749/3110834).

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank you for your comment. It's not just about the visibilty of the column, because I have many navigation properties in each class and I don't want to load them. For the query, I tried to use a query, but the grid wouldn't be editable. I'm sorry, I'm just beginning EF.

Comment: Just disable `LazyLoading`, then make sure you don't `Include` any navigation property unless it's necessary. That would be enough.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank you for the note, I use a class with the singleton pattern to return a single DataContext. Editing and saving the changes works when I bind it directly like the first method in my question, but when I bind using a query, editing does not work

Comment: By query I don't mean anonymous objects. Just disable `LazyLoading`, then make sure you don't `Include` any navigation property unless it's necessary. That would be enough. Then when you get `var data = DBContext.DRIVERs.Local.ToBindingList();` Then the list will not include any data for the navigation properties.

Comment: @RezaAghaei so it's safe to remove the Navigation properties from the generated model code like  public virtual EQUIPMENT EQUIPMENT { get; set; } in my example?

Comment: @RezaAghaei If I set LazyLoadingEnabled to false, the navigation properties still show in the grid. My question is can I simply delete the navigation property (for example delete the line :    public virtual EQUIPMENT EQUIPMENT { get; set; }  in class Driver .... is it safe to do so? ..... I'm sorry I didn't understand what you mean by "You should to remove navigation properties",  I guess you meant not

Comment: You **should not** remove navigation properties. Instead, when initializing dbcontext do the following: `var db = new MyDbContext();` `db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` Then for getting data, simply get data this way: `data = db.MyEntity.Local.ToBindingList();`.

Comment: For visibility, read my first comment.

Comment: @RezaAghaei the [Browsable(false)] worked , thank you

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading navigation properties and showing them are two different topics.

**Prevent Loading**

Disable lazy loading and just include those navigation properties which you need

```
var db = new MyDbContext(); 
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
data = db.MyEntity.Local.ToBindingList();
```

**Prevent Showing**

Decorate the navigation property by `[Browsable(false)]`.

```
[Browsable(false)]
public virtual EQUIPMENT EQUIPMENT { get; set; }
```

Or

Set the column visibility to false:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["EQUIPMENT"].Visible = false
```

Or

At the first place, define just a set of columns which you want for your `DataGridView` using designer or using code. Then `DataGridView` will show just those columns which you defined:

```
var DRIVERIDColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
DRIVERIDColumn.Name = "DRIVERID";
DRIVERIDColumn.HeaderText = "Id";
DRIVERIDColumn.DataPropertyName= "DRIVERID";
// ...
dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(DRIVERIDColumn /*...*/);
// ...
```

Comment: Make sure you read this as well: [What is the correct way to use Entity Framework as datasource for DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42114690/3110834) You can take advantage of designer features.